# Duplicate objects transformation applies to both objects

Tags: transforms, linked-data

I'm facing this frustrating "feature" that I can't seem to remedy; when I duplicate an object (and now, even when I create two completely new objects), their transformations/scaling is synchronized. This is extremely annoying when trying to use any sort of transformation keyboard shortcut.

It should be noted by going to the properties menu (<kbd>N</kbd>) and manually setting the properties works just fine.

For instance, here is *just* the camera selected (trust me, I made sure):
[image]

And when I try to transform by clicking+dragging on the X axis OR by hitting <kbd>G</kbd>-><kbd>X</kbd>, this happens:
[image]

They are not grouped (verified by going to the Groups list up in the Scene panel) and they do not have parents (verified by going to *Object*->*Relations*).

I have tried the unlink command as well, to no avail.

I have seriously run out of options; what did I change to have my <kbd>G</kbd>-><kbd>X</kbd> shortcuts transform multiple objects? It seems completely at random, too; certain objects seemed to be "linked" to other random objects, and this "linking" is guaranteed when duplicating *even when I do a non-linking duplicate* (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>).

What gives?

Comment: Is there any way you could share the .blend file for this? First guess would be that you've somehow put a copy location constraint on the mesh that's moving with your camera.

Comment: Images could be uploaded directly into the question body, it's quite easy. They weren't uploaded and now aren't available

Comment: @MrZak I couldn't due to my rep. This was almost 6 years ago. Give me a break.

Comment: Thank you for fixing the images @Glorfindel :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This could be...

- Proportional editing, *(disable in 3d view header)*
- Objects can share an action (shared animation data), *(check the action space with each object selected)*
- a constraint, check object constraints
- a driver *(unlikely this would be setup by accident, but drivers can do this still)*

Comment: For crying out loud, it was the first one. I read [this link](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Proportional_Edit) to find out I had hit `O` at some point. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 3):

For debugging cases like this you could try using the following debugging tools

1. Keep an eye on the View3D Header for information regarding the current modal operator. In your case, you should see proportional editing messages.
2. In the View3D Properties Panel (<kbd>N</kbd> key), under Display Panel check the Relationships option. (in case there are constraints setup like Child-Of, Copy-Transform)