# Why is an object stuck to another?

Tags: objects

So I created a Cube in Blender and then I created an Empty beside the Cube (in object mode). Now, when I move the Empty around, the Cube follows... Why?

Comment: Is there a circle in the middle of the screen when you move the empty?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Duplicate objects transformation applies to both objects](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1495/duplicate-objects-transformation-applies-to-both-objects)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You more than likely hit <kbd>O</kbd> by accident, this enables proportional editing in *object mode* just as it does in *edit mode* and can cause nearby objects to mimic the one(s) being transformed.

Just turn it off by clicking the blue icon or by pressing <kbd>O</kbd> again.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the cube is parented to the empty, making it follow it's transformations. You can remove the parenting by selecting the cube and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>.

Parenting relations can be set up by first selecting the child object(s), and then adding the parent object to selection making it the active object, and hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>