# Change height of an inset extrusion

Tags: mesh, transforms

I'm trying to change the height of an inset extrusion on a block mesh, but the object is distorting when I attempt to change the height.  Below is a snap of two block meshes.  Each has an inset of the top face, and an extrusion of the inner face.  One is up, the other down.

I can change the right object's top face (<kbd>G</kbd> then <kbd>Z</kbd> for the height), with no distortion to the cube.  However when I change the left cube's lower face the entire cube distorts.  I need to do small adjustments to the inner surface depth only.

Before
[image]

After
[image]

Comment: Related (but in object mode): http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1765/599

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have [proportional editing](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Proportional_Edit) (<kbd>O</kbd>) enabled:

[image]

Disable it by pressing <kbd>O</kbd> again or selecting *disabled* in *3D view > Header*.