# Why can't I transform faces, edges, or vertices without transforming the whole object?

Tags: mesh, transforms, vertices, edges, faces

My problem is that I **sometimes** lose the ability to independently translate or otherwise transform any parts of a single mesh. If I try, for example, to just translate several faces, edges, or vertices, then the entire mesh will stretch and displace itself in order to follow the translation. Or, alternatively, if I try to translate just one face then the whole mesh will move as if I'm translating in Object Mode.

I'm not really sure I know how to describe this problem properly. I don't even know how to reliably reproduce it. It seems to happen to any given mesh at random, and it doesn't stop happening to that mesh unless I delete and remake it.

I assume that I must be doing something wrong to cause this to happen. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/18797/599

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to turn off proportional editing

[image]

Or use the shortcut: <kbd>O</kbd> key.

Proportional editing in action:

[image]

Comment: Oh, hey, that did it! Wow, thanks. Save for accidental keypresses, is there anything that could be passively turning that on?

Comment: @MatthewHarrison Not that I know of, unless you have some odd scripts or unusual setup. I think missed key presses are most likely

Comment: @MatthewHarrison Please accept this answer if it helped you (using the checkmark), as soon as you can (there is a time limit before you can do that)

Comment: Ah, okay. Also, checked! Thanks for the reminder. I'm new to the whole StackExchange network.