# Weird geometry when using Mirror + skin modifiers

Tags: modeling, modifiers, mirror

I'm following a course from CGCookie (Basics of character modelling). I'm trying to pull one of the vertices backwards:

there's a mirror modifier on, as well as skin and subsurf.

[image]

All the geometry gets warped:

[image]

Same thing happens when I'm trying to extrude another vertex from the bottom one.

Can anyone please help? I tried asking the question on the course's page, but the mods deleted it for some reason.

Comment: Forgot to mention - there's a mirror modifier on, as well as skin and subsurf.

Comment: Does this help? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27394/strange-problem-cant-transform-faces-edges-or-vertices-without-transforming/27395#27395

Comment: I'm afraid not. That was the first thing I checked. Thanks for the clarity edit though ;).

Comment: I think I'd just better give you the .blend, since character modeling is completely new for me and I'm flying blind here. [link](http://www.fast-files.com/getfile.aspx?file=92721)

Comment: And here's the part of the course I followed: [link](https://cgcookie.com/blender/lessons/2-building-a-basemesh-with-the-skin-modifier/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Skin Modifier is generating the geometry from the root vertex (marked with dashed circle around it), and if its not on the mirror axis that will generate mesh errors.

To fix that select the vertex of the groin area and in Skin Modifier click **Mark Root.**

[image]

Comment: Useful clarification of the problem statement.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you so much for the answer and for the explanation! I was so sure I tried doing it before.