# Camera follow object and wont allow to move with 3d cursor

Tags: 3d-view

Ok, so when i am doing my thing, modeling a gun, all the sudden, I cant move my part by the arrows! when i move my object by pressing G or clicking it, the 3D View Camera follows it to! I dont know why all the sudden this occured to me. I might of pressed something on accident.

I dont want this to happen. I tried Reseting the settings, but it looks like its just my project. I am new to blender and I know some advanced things, but i dont know how to fix this. Is this a bug? Can this be fixed? It is very annoying.

Comment: *"when i am doing my thing"*, *"cant move my part by the arrows"* can you include at least some information about *what* are you actually doing and what isn't as expected? Screenshots, description for them.. The only guess I have is that if you move path to which camera is parented camera will move as well (so the view from it). Your question is not clear

Comment: [proportional editing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/27394/2217)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to fix this. This is probably a glitch but i grouped the object that the camera follow and ungrouped it. It fixed my problem

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have `Lock To Object` enabled. In that case, the Blender Camera will always keep a certain object - which is chosen in the list - centered in the Viewport. `Lock To Object` is enabled if there's an object selected in the field, see screenshot below where it says "Cube". Click the little <kbd>X</kbd> next to the object name on the right to disable the locking:

[image]