# cant move a single vertex

Tags: modeling

[image]

Hi i'd like to know how to move just one vertex, i need to change the position of a vertex but when i select and move  the other vertex come together. I just started blender yesterday and today is my attempt to try model with tutorials but it still very hard!! i need to do what this guy did at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dgUx8v6u7tM 3:24

EDIT The Proportional Editing is already disabled

Comment: There are two main ways that more than one vertex can move when you have only one selected . 1) you have proportional editing switched on. 'O' toggles it. 2) You have the results of a subdivision showing in Edit Mode.. This looks like 1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I transform faces, edges, or vertices without transforming the whole object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27394/why-cant-i-transform-faces-edges-or-vertices-without-transforming-the-whole-o)

Comment: Most likely you have double vertices. So you actually move a vertex, but there are 2 vertices connected to edges in the same spot which is why you select the wrong one. Try to select all and press W > Remove Doubles

Comment: @Duarte Carefully observe the menu bar. It would say ***Proportion Size*** if proportional editing were enabled, wouldn't it?

Comment: True, you are right. Now that you mention it, upon closer inspection the second 3D view does seem to indicate lots of overlapping or duplicate geometry

Comment: yes the  the Proportional Editing is already disabled :S i dont know what is hapenning , i need to do what that guy did in the video

Comment: @MrZak First,thank you so much for your reply, can you also tell me how to select All? without clicking every vertice?

Comment: the 'A' key toggles between selecting / deselecting all, and another thing to check is if you have snapping enabled (little Magnet icon in the bottom header menu) and / or an option right next to that menu that allows you to 'auto-merge' vertices that get snapped to each other. Good luck!

Comment: @MrZak omg you solved my problem!!! as Shiprex told me to press A i select everything and then i ´pressed the key you mentioned >W>Remove Doubles and it worked!! thank you so much i was stuck in this problem and finally i can keep going on now :)!! Thank you all for the replies Shiprex,Duarte,Leander and Robin.

Comment: I dont want to be anyoing but is there a specific reason you are using 2.79 (unless your GPU does not support newer OpenGL)? You should at least be on 2.83 LTS. If it is for learning 2.91.2 should be fine too.

Answer (score 1):

You might have proportional editing on. If you want to use it you have to press <kbd>G</kbd> and then move <kbd>MMB [image: MMB]</kbd> up to shrink the size of the area.