# Scale edge loop

Tags: origin

I've been out of Blender for over a year and trying to catch up on it again.
I have created some bent tubes by following a Nurbs Curve path with a circle and then solidifying it.  After doing other work I see the size of the ends on some tubes need adjusting to fit with other geometry.  If I select the edge loop on the end of a tube and try scaling it the scaling takes place based on the Origin Point of the tube not at the Edge Loop.  I have tried setting the Cursor to the center of Edge Loop and then moving the Origin Point of the tube using Ctrl+Shift+Alt+C.  If done in Object Mode this seems to work until I shift into Edit Mode.  Then scaling takes place based on the original location of the Origin Point not the new location.  Trying to move the Origin Point in Edit Mode using this method just produces an error message.
How can I scale this Edge Loop?

[image]

Comment: What version of Blender? Normally if you select vertices in Edit mode and set Pivot point to Median Point or Bounding Box depending on the case scaling will work based on selection. No need to change origin point of the object

Comment: Ver. 2.79.  Setting the Pivot point to Median Point is better, but the previous Edge Loop is scaling as well.

Comment: I can't know what you mean "previous edge loop is scaling as well". If you mean that while you scale selected edge loop another one next to it is being scaled as well then turn off Proportional Edit as one option, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27394/why-cant-i-transform-faces-edges-or-vertices-without-transforming-the-whole-o/27395

Comment: Yup, that's what I meant.   Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Without changing the origin you can use Pivot Point>Median Point

[image]