# How to turn off what seems to be an auto extrude

Tags: modeling

I'm new to blender (and in fact modelling in general) and I don't know the controls. I think at one point I must have toggled something wrong and now instead of dragging vertices around right mouse button extrudes from whatever is selected.
In addition selecting a vertex and trying to move it manually with the X/Y/Z transform boxes also extrudes.

Does anyone know what I've done and how to reverse it?

Comment: It's hard to say what happens really. normal controls are G for grab (moving vertices/edges/feces) and E for extrusions. right clicking allow you to select but Ctrl+right click does extrusion. Try to check your Ctrl key

Comment: Blender has no auto extrude functionality like that. Unless your keys are faulty or sticking, most possible scenario is that you might have duplicate faces/verts and or have proportional editing on. Or since you are new, it might just be proportional editing you are confusing with extrusion. A video/gif if possible would be nice or save the file you are in and upload it to http://pasteall.org/blend and share the link here.

Comment: You can also try 'File->Load Factory Settings'

Comment: yes it turns out i had many duplicate vertexes. thanks @iKlsR

Comment: +1 for sticky keys - Ctrl-Click performs an extrude of selection. Maybe check for sticky keys in system controls.

Comment: Also remember you can right click and drag to transform geometry.

Comment: I have the same problem. The Extrude button on the tools menu is highlighted as soon as the default cube image appears, and I don't know how to turn it off. I was so frustrated that I trashed the Blender installation, and reinstalled it. The problem occurs with the default cube, so I doubt that duplicate vertices are the problem. Also, I don't see a blue icon in the view menu. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender has no auto extrude functionality like what you describe to my knowledge. Based on your description, the most likely culprits are.

1. Duplicate vertices, to fix, <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Edit* mode and perform a *Remove Doubles* operation from the <kbd>W</kbd> specials menu.
2. Proportional Editing, this is usually indicated by a circle that shows the region being affected, check your view header for a blue icon/toggle this with <kbd>O</kbd>. See [Why is an object stuck to another?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1765/12)

Or it could be a combination of both of the above.