Object gets "parented" to another object for no reason?
So this really weird thing keeps happening and I have no idea why: if I move an object, randomly some other objects will just "stick" to it. In this video it happens with an identical mesh only, but a lot of times it parents several different objects and it's making me go crazy!
Does anyone know a cause or something?
Video in question

This is obviously a very rigged and very animated scene, so it is impossible to tell from the video alone what’s going on. We could try to look at the blend file, but I’m guessing you don’t want to share the whole thing. So, (after saving as a new file) select the two objects that are moving together, invert the selection, delete all of that, make sure the effect still happens, then share the resulting file via blend-exchange.com

It may be because you have proportional editing turned on (hilighted bullseye in the middle of the top toolbar). Hit O to turn it off and see if that fixes the problem.

Apparently I had proportional editing turned on. Thank you, John Eason!

No problem. It's been asked about and answered several times before here so I won't add it as an answer this time.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1765/why-is-an-object-stuck-to-another https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27394/why-cant-i-transform-faces-edges-or-vertices-without-transforming-the-whole-o/
