# Rescaling/transform affects 2 objects instead of just the one selected?

Tags: transforms, selection-tools

Whenever I try to create a new object and scale/transform it in object mode, it automatically selects another object and scales that object too without me selecting that object.
I think this has something to do with the origin of the object that is automatically selected given that it has the same origin as the new object created.
Note: The object that is automatically selected is not highlighted in the scene section and I cannot deselect it.
Any idea how I can fix this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Could you upload your .blend and/or some screenshots?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1495/599

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you added you new object in *Edit mode*. Press <kbd>tab</kbd> to toggle between edit mode and object mode.

[image: edit mode menu]

If in fact you have one object, then in edit press <kbd>P</kbd> then choose *loose parts*. That will split the object in to multiple pieces.

Comment: I created the object in object mode, not edit mode.