# Why is my model moving vertexes that aren't selected, when scaling

Tags: mesh

When I extend my "cylinder" by using the <kbd>E</kbd> key and attempt to scale it

[image]http://prntscr.com/axq436

It also moves some vertexes along with it.

Comment: Well ***, i thought i disabled it?!                                                                                         
Thanks for answering a simple question.

Comment: Change my comment to an answer. :)

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1495/duplicate-objects-transformation-applies-to-both-objects, also http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27394/strange-problem-cant-transform-faces-edges-or-vertices-without-transforming

Answer (score 2):

Check if proportional editing is on, press the shortcut key <kbd>O</kbd> will toggle the setting.

Click [Here](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/proportional_edit.html) for more information on Proportional Editing.