# How Do I Move a Face Entirely on Its Own?

Tags: modeling, mesh, transforms, faces

I fairly new to blender and i'm trying to move a specific face on its own. When I have the face selected and use the move controls, it tugs the surrounding area with it. I was doing it before but I think I accidentally hit a shortcut, and now it no longer responds this way. How do I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Duplicate objects transformation applies to both objects](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1495/duplicate-objects-transformation-applies-to-both-objects)

Comment: are you talking about the face is stretching the edges it is connected to, or all the surrounding geometry?

Comment: maybe related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27394/why-cant-i-transform-faces-edges-or-vertices-without-transforming-the-whole-o/27395#27395

Answer (score 2):

I think that you want to duplicate the face. You want to move the face without affecting the rest of geometry. To do this select the face and press shift+D and place your face where you want.

After you have duplicated and you want to delete your original face, press X to delete and select Only faces.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily go into edit mode and select the Face you want, After you have selected it press P, it  should open a small window, then just click selection and now you have made that face its own object. GL

Answer (score 0):

When you press <kbd>G</kbd>  check the mouse wheel up and then move mouse up and down to do what you mean, you will be known.